# comparing two files and get the matched line from second file

Tags: perl, unix, awk

File 1:

```
Locus        Gene name
chr1         AT1G27893.6
chr3         AT3G28270.3
chr4         AT5G46005.1
chr8         AT8G59300.5
```

File 2:

```
Gene name              Type                  Short_description
AT1G01010.1       protein_coding        AP2/B3-like transcriptional factor 
AT3G28270.3       protein_coding        NAC domain containing protein 1
AT8G59300.5       protein_coding        mitochondrial ribosomal protein S7
ATMG01270.1       protein_coding        FRIGIDA like 2  family member
```

output:

Locus          Gene name                Type                   Short_description

```
chr3           AT3G28270.3        protein_coding        NAC domain containing protein 1
chr4           AT8G59300.5        protein_coding        mitochondrial ribosomal protein S7
```

Code i used

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){ print a[$1]; next}1' file2 file1
```

I am not able to get the output as i need , its printing all lines in file2.

Comment: Why are you using field separator comma `","` in the awk command?

Comment: I were wrong so i tried awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' File1 File2 : But am not able to get the Locus column. can you help me on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `join`

```
join -1 2 -2 1 file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Gene Locus name name Type Short_description
AT3G28270.3 chr3 protein_coding NAC domain containing protein 1
AT8G59300.5 chr8 protein_coding mitochondrial ribosomal protein S7
```